# How to get the pop up for kendo drop down if data is not matched

Tags: kendo-ui

I can able to filer the matched data using filter button.How to get the popup window if there is no matched data after clicking the filter data.Present If there is no matched data the table is showing  empty instead of that how to rise a pop to tell no matched data to filter

```
// Set up information window
$("#filter-msg").kendoWindow({
    modal: true,
    visible: false
});

// Set up date pickers
$("#datetimepicker1").kendoDatePicker({});
$("#datetimepicker2").kendoDatePicker({});

// Set up DDL
var categories = $("#categories").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: "Select category...",
    dataTextField: "CategoryName",
    dataValueField: "CategoryID",
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");

var products = $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    cascadeFrom: "categories",
    optionLabel: "Select product...",
    dataTextField: "ProductName",
    dataValueField: "ProductID",
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");

var orders = $("#orders").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    cascadeFrom: "products",
    optionLabel: "Select order...",
    dataTextField: "Order.ShipCity",
    dataValueField: "OrderID",
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Order_Details?$expand=Order"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");


// Bind "click" event on button "Filter"
$("#filter").on("click", function () {
    var mindate = $('#datetimepicker1').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var maxdate = $('#datetimepicker2').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var product = $("#products").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var order = $("#orders").data("kendoDropDownList").value();

    if (!mindate || !maxdate || !product || !order) {
        var content = "";
        if (!mindate) 
            content += "<div class=\"k-error-colored\">mindate is not defined!</div>";
        if (!maxdate) 
            content += "<div class=\"k-error-colored\">maxdate is not defined!</div>";
        if (!product) 
            content += "<div class=\"k-error-colored\">product is not defined!</div>";
        if (!order) 
            content += "<div class=\"k-error-colored\">order is not defined!</div>";

        $("#filter-msg").data("kendoWindow")
            .content(content)
            .center()
            .open();
        return false;
    }

    var condition = {
        logic: "and",
        filters: [{
            field: "OrderDate",
            operator: "ge",
            value: mindate
        }, {
            field: "OrderDate",
            operator: "le",
            value: maxdate
        }]
    };

    grid.dataSource.filter(condition);
});




var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    OrderID: {
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    Freight: {
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    ShipName: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    OrderDate: {
                        type: "date"
                    },
                    ShipCity: {
                        type: "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
    },
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "OrderID",
        filterable: false
    },
        "Freight", {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        width: 100,
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
    }, {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name",
        width: 200
    }, {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City"
    }]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Here is the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XHW3w/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done, you can check using `length` property of `dataSource.data`

Here is the updated **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHW3w/10/)**

```
grid.dataSource.filter(condition);
console.log(grid.dataSource.data.length);
if(grid.dataSource.data.length <= 1)
    $("#filter-msg").data("kendoWindow")
        .content("<div class=\"k-error-colored\">No record found!</div>")
        .center()
        .open();
```